# What is the equivalent of abstract classes in Go?

Tags: go

I want only a particular set of structs to be able to call a function. The function has the same implementation for all the structs but the values in the fields of these structs will be different. In Java, this could be done using an abstract class. How to do this in Go?

Equivalent code in Java:

```
abstract class Parent {
    int numb;

    void doSomething() {
        print(numb);
    }
}

class ChildA extends Parent {}

class ChildB extends Parent {}

main() {
    ChildA a = new ChildA();
    a.numb = 1;
    a.doSomething();

    ChildB b = new ChildB();
    b.numb = 2;
    b.doSomething();
}
```

Comment: "I want only a particular set of structs to be able to call a function." Put the function and all of its callers in the same package and nothing else. Don't export the function.

Answer (score -1):

In Go, you don't have traditional classes like in Java. However, you can achieve similar functionality using struct methods. Here's an example:

```
enter code here
package main

import "fmt"

type Parent struct {
    numb int
}

func (p *Parent) doSomething() {
    fmt.Println(p.numb)
}

type ChildA struct {
    Parent
}

type ChildB struct {
    Parent
}

func main() {
    a := ChildA{Parent: Parent{numb: 1}}
    a.doSomething()

    b := ChildB{Parent: Parent{numb: 2}}
    b.doSomething()
}
```